# How to extract a LookupCustomerIdResult element value from XML text using t-sql XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I want to determine LookupCustomerIdResult value from following XML SOAP 1.1 response:

```
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000)
SET @ResponseText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LookupCustomerIdResponse xmlns="http://www.alarm.com/WebServices">
      <LookupCustomerIdResult>54949945</LookupCustomerIdResult>
    </LookupCustomerIdResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
```

I tried following but I get NULL result:

```
Declare @XmlResponse as xml
select @XmlResponse = CAST(@ResponseText as xml) 
DECLARE @customerID VARCHAR(500)

SELECT @customerID = @XmlResponse.value
('(/LookupCustomerIdResponse/LookupCustomerIdResult)[1]', 'varchar(550)')

SELECT @customerID
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least there are two problems, **first** `LookupCustomerIdResponse` is not the root element so you can't start with `/LookupCustomerIdResponse`. This can be fixed by using `descendant-or-self` axis (`//`) instead.

The **second** problem is, that the XML has default namespace declaration -namespace declared without prefix- at the `LookupCustomerIdResponse` level. That causes `LookupCustomerIdResponse` and all the descendant elements without explicit prefix -and without local default namespace- to be considered in that same namespace. You can use [`;WITH XMLNAMESPACES()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx) construct to specify default namespace to be used in the following XPath/XQuery statements.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(default 'http://www.alarm.com/WebServices')
SELECT @customerID = @XmlResponse.value
('(//LookupCustomerIdResponse/LookupCustomerIdResult)[1]', 'varchar(550)')

SELECT @customerID
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db/32)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
54949945
```

Comment: @PiyushVarma good decision to ask in a new thread. Also, please consider [to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer since it solved the problem/question. Thanks